# Тест на python. Переход между вопросами

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне необходимо сделать тест. Я пытаюсь сделать переход в test2 через счётчик. Как вариант думал прописывать для каждого вопроса отдельную функцию, думал над классом. Но надеюсь всё-таки сделать с переменной. Надо чтобы текст вопроса зависел от переменной номера вопроса, и переменная увеличивалась по каждому нажатию кнопок да/нет, но при этом ещё требуется чтобы за да давали 1 балл, а за нет ничего не давали. Расположение и команды кнопок не меняются. Test1 и Test3 затрагивать не надо. Ниже то, что у меня пока получилось. Заранее спасибо.

Код:

```
from tkinter import *
#test1 - самооценка
#test2 - приятно ли с вами общаться
#test3 - благоразумие
point = 1
a = 1
root = Tk()
root.title("Психологический тест")
root.geometry('700x700')
def test1_fun():
    def test1_shutdown():
        test1.destroy()
    def test1_start():
        test1_descr.destroy()
        test1_ready.destroy()
        test1_notready.destroy()
    test1 = Tk()
    test1.title("Тест 1. Уровень Вашей самооценки")
    test1.geometry('500x500')
    test1_descr = Label(test1, text="Вы готовы пройти тест из 15 вопросов?", font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
    test1_descr.place(relx=0, rely=0.3, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
    test1_ready = Button(test1, text="Да", background="gray90", font="Arial 16", command=test1_start)
    test1_notready = Button(test1, text="Нет", background="gray90", font="Arial 16", command=test1_shutdown)
    test1_ready.place(relx=0.73, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
    test1_notready.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
def test2_fun():
    def test2_shutdown():
        test2.destroy()
    def test2_questions():
        a=1
        def test2_yes():
            global point
            global a
            point+=1
            a+=1

        def test2_no():
            global point
            global a
            point -= 0  
            a += 1
        def test2_answer_buttons():
            test2_answer_yes = Button(test2, text="Да", background="gray90", font="Arial 16", command=test2_yes)
            test2_answer_no = Button(test2, text="Нет", background="gray90", font="Arial 16", command=test2_no)
            test2_answer_yes.place(relx=0.73, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
            test2_answer_no.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
        question_num = (f"Вопрос номер {a}")
        test2_question_num = Label(test2, text=question_num, font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
        test2_question_num.place(relx=0, rely=0.3, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
        while a>=1 and a<=11:
            if a == 1:
                test2_question_text = "Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?"
                test2_question_label = Label(test2, text=test2_question_text, font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
                test2_question_label.place(relx=0, rely=0.6, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
                test2_answer_buttons()
            elif a == 2:
                test2_question_text = "Вы всегда можете найти тему для разговора даже с незнакомым человеком?"
                test2_question_label = Label(test2, text=test2_question_text, font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
                test2_question_label.place(relx=0, rely=0.6, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
                test2_answer_buttons()
            elif a == 3:
                test2_question_text = "Вы всегда внимательно слушаете собеседника?"
                test2_question_label = Label(test2, text=test2_question_text, font="Arial 20", background="gray93",justify=CENTER)
                test2_question_label.place(relx=0, rely=0.6, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
                test2_answer_buttons()
            elif a == 4:
                test2_question_text = "Любите ли Вы давать советы?"
                test2_question_label = Label(test2, text=test2_question_text, font="Arial 20", background="gray93",justify=CENTER)
                test2_question_label.place(relx=0, rely=0.6, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
                test2_answer_buttons()
            elif a == 5:
                test2_question_text = "Если тема разговора Вам неинтересна, станете ли показывать это собеседнику?"
                test2_question_label = Label(test2, text=test2_question_text, font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
                test2_question_label.place(relx=0, rely=0.6, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
                test2_answer_buttons()
            elif a == 6:
                test2_question_text = "Раздражаетесь ли Вы, когда вас не слушают?"
                test2_question_label = Label(test2, text=test2_question_text, font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
                test2_question_label.place(relx=0, rely=0.6, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
                test2_answer_buttons()
            elif a == 7:
                test2_question_text = "У Вас есть собственное мнение по любому вопросу?"
                test2_question_label = Label(test2, text=test2_question_text, font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
                test2_question_label.place(relx=0, rely=0.6, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
                test2_answer_buttons()
            elif a == 8:
                test2_question_text = "Если тема разговора Вам незнакома, станете ли её развивать?"
                test2_question_label = Label(test2, text=test2_question_text, font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
                test2_question_label.place(relx=0, rely=0.6, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
                test2_answer_buttons()
            elif a == 9:
                test2_question_text = "Вы любите быть центром внимания?"
                test2_question_label = Label(test2, text=test2_question_text, font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
                test2_question_label.place(relx=0, rely=0.6, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
                test2_answer_buttons()
            elif a == 10:
                test2_question_text = "Есть ли хотя бы три предмета, по которым Вы обладаете прочными знаниями?"
                test2_question_label = Label(test2, text=test2_question_text, font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
                test2_question_label.place(relx=0, rely=0.6, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
                test2_answer_buttons()
            elif a == 11:
                test2_question_text = "Вы хороший оратор?"
                test2_question_label = Label(test2, text=test2_question_text, font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
                test2_question_label.place(relx=0, rely=0.6, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
                test2_answer_buttons()
            test2_questions()
    def test2_start():
        test2_descr.destroy()
        test2_ready.destroy()
        test2_notready.destroy()
    test2 = Tk()
    test2.title("Тест 2. Приятно ли с Вами общаться?")
    test2.geometry('500x500')
    test2_descr = Label(test2, text="Вы готовы пройти тест из 11 вопросов?", font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
    test2_descr.place(relx=0, rely=0.3, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
    test2_ready = Button(test2, text="Да", background="gray90", font="Arial 16", command=test2_start)
    test2_notready = Button(test2, text="Нет", background="gray90", font="Arial 16", command=test2_shutdown)
    test2_ready.place(relx=0.73, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
    test2_notready.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
def test3_fun():
    def test3_shutdown():
        test3.destroy()
    def test3_start():
        test3_descr.destroy()
        test3_ready.destroy()
        test3_notready.destroy()
    test3 = Tk()
    test3.title("Тест 3. Благоразумны ли вы?")
    test3.geometry('500x500')
    test3_descr = Label(test3, text="Вы готовы пройти тест из 11 вопросов?", font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
    test3_descr.place(relx=0, rely=0.3, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
    test3_ready = Button(test3, text="Да", background="gray90", font="Arial 16", command=test3_start)
    test3_notready = Button(test3, text="Нет", background="gray90", font="Arial 16", command=test3_shutdown)
    test3_ready.place(relx=0.73, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
    test3_notready.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
choose_lab = Label(root, text="Выберите тест", width=30, height=1, font="Arial 20", background="gray93")
choose_lab.place(x=100, y=1)
test1_but = Button(root, text="Уровень Вашей самооценки.", width=30, height=2, font="Arial 20", background="gray90", command=test1_fun)
test1_but.place(x=100, y=180)
test2_but = Button(root, text="Приятно ли с Вами общаться?", width=30, height=2, font="Arial 20", background="gray90", command=test2_fun)
test2_but.place(x=100, y=380)
test3_but = Button(root, text="Благоразумны ли Вы?", width=30, height=2, font="Arial 20", background="gray90", command=test3_fun)
test3_but.place(x=100, y=580)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: вопрос не ясен,- тест1 пуст, как через него при помощи счётчика перейти в тест2? да и организация программы ужасна, нет, имеется в виду ужасна,- мб исспользовать sqlite со структурой типа table=test, min_for_view, max_for_view,question

Comment: Имеется ввиду переход между вопросами внутри теста, а не между тестами